# Obtain static values from C++ .o file using php

Tags: php, c++

I have a compiled C++ object file. And that object file contains a huge list of static constant values (as a matter of fact that .o file contains only static values). Is there any way I can read those static values using php? I can not copy those values into php and need to read them directly.

Thanks, to anyone for their response.

Comment: If they're really static, then there shouldn't be any public record of them being in the file at all. The C++ compiler is free to remove static things that aren't used in the given translation unit. If they're to be externally visible, then they should have been marked extern. Are you sure the file really has what you think it has?

Comment: Hoping he meant "static" as in "not dynamic" instead of `static` linkage. Or maybe `static`-storage declarations in functions or classes. BTW, a shout out to Kerninghan, Ritchie, and Stroustrup for making one keyword do so many completely different things, and ANSI and ISO for codifying it instead of deprecating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dump out the contents of the .o using `nm` or `objdump` and manually parse using regexes into a php header file.  This has the disadvantage that it's not "live" so if the .o is rebuilt you will have to synch up manually, but it definitely sounds like you need a one-time "quick and dirty" method.

Comment: I think `objdump` is what you want; `nm` will just give you addresses and/or sizes.

Comment: Thanks, It was nasty and hard but I ended up settling for objdump

Answer (score 1):

Does PHP have wrappers for `dlopen` and `dlsym`?

If yes, you can link that `.o` file into a `.so` and use dynamic linking to access it.